# ApplicativeDo in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

AFAIK one of the new additions to GHC8 is the `ApplicativeDo` language extension, which desugars the do-notation to the corresponding `Applicative` methods (`<$>`, `<*>`) if possible. I have the following questions.

How does it decide whether the desugaring to `Applicative` methods is possible? From what I know, it does a dependency check (if the later depends on the result of former) to decide the eligibility. Are there any other criteria?

Although this addition makes applicative code easier to read for classes that don't have any Monad instance (maybe ?). But for structures that both have a Monad and an Applicative instance: Is this a recommended practice (from the readability perspective)? Are there any other benefits?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How does it decide whether the desugaring to `Applicative` methods is possible? From what I know, it does a dependency check (if the later depends on the result of former) to decide the eligibility. Are there any other criteria?

The [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/list-comp/applicativedo.pdf) and [trac page](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo) are the best sources of information. Some points:

- `ApplicativeDo` uses applicatives wherever possible - including mixing them with `>>=` in some cases where only part of the `do` block is applicative
- A sort of directed graph of dependencies is constructed to see which parts can be "parallelized"
- Sometimes there is no obvious best translation of this graph! In this case, GHC chooses the translation that is (roughly speaking) locally smallest

> Although this addition makes applicative code easier to read for classes that don't have any `Monad` instance (maybe ?). But for structures that both have a `Monad` and an `Applicative` instance: Is this a recommended practice (from the readability perspective)? Are there any other benefits?

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38719766/3072788) about the difference between `Applicative` and `Monad`. To quote directly:

> To deploy `<*>`, you choose two computations, one of a function, the other of an argument, then their values are combined by application. To deploy `>>=`, you choose one computation, and you explain how you will make use of its resulting values to choose the next computation. It is the difference between "batch mode" and "interactive" operation.

A prime example of this sort of thing is the [`Haxl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl-0.4.0.1/docs/Haxl-Core.html#t:GenHaxl) monad (designed by Facebook) which is all about fetching data from some external source. Using `Applicative`, these requests can happen in parallel while `Monad` forces the requests to be sequential. In fact, this example is what motivated Simon Marlow at Facebook to make the `ApplicativeDo` extension in the first place and write the quoted paper about it.

In general, most `Monad` instances don't necessarily benefit from `Applicative`. From the same answer I quoted above:

> I appreciate that `ApplicativeDo` is a great way to make more applicative (and in some cases that means faster) programs that were written in monadic style that you haven't the time to refactor. But otherwise, I'd argue applicative-when-you-can-but-monadic-when-you-must is also the better way to see what's going on.

So: use `Applicative` over `Monad` when possible, and exploit `ApplicativeDo` when it really is nicer to write (like it must have been in some cases at Facebook) than the corresponding applicative expression.