# ApplicativeDo pragma and Applicative Functor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

An example from [Functor, Applicative, and Monad](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/advanced-haskell/functors-applicative-functors-and-monads)
 slightly changed:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}

import Safe (readMay)
-- import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))

displayAge maybeAge =
    case maybeAge of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "You provided invalid input"
        Just age -> putStrLn $ "In that year, you will be: " ++ show age

yearDiff futureYear birthYear = futureYear - birthYear

maybeAge fS bS = do 
   fI <- readMay fS
   bI <- readMay bS
   pure $ yearDiff fI bI       

main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter your birth year"
    birthYearString <- getLine
    putStrLn "Please enter some year in the future"
    futureYearString <- getLine
    displayAge $ maybeAge birthYearString futureYearString
```

where `maybeAge` with `do` I used instead of

```
maybeAge fS bS = yearDiff <$> readMay fS <*> readMay bS
```

I have the 2 questions:

1. How can I check does `maybeAge` use Applicative Functor semantic or Monad one in this case?
2. What is an advantage in that case if Applicative Functor used?

About: [ApplicativeDo](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ApplicativeDo).

Comment: About: [ApplicativeDo](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ApplicativeDo).

Comment: and [ApplicativeDo in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689441/applicativedo-in-haskell)

Comment: Just a side note. You can make `yearDiff = subtract`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a self-contained example out of yours:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}

import Text.Read (readMaybe)

displayAge :: Maybe Int -> IO ()
displayAge maybeAge =
    case maybeAge of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "You provided invalid input"
        Just age -> putStrLn $ "In that year, you will be: " ++ show age

yearDiff :: Int -> Int -> Int
yearDiff  = (-)

maybeAge :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
maybeAge fS bS = do 
   fI <- readMaybe fS
   bI <- readMaybe bS
   pure $ yearDiff fI bI

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter your birth year"
    birthYearString <- getLine
    putStrLn "Please enter some year in the future"
    futureYearString <- getLine
    displayAge $ maybeAge futureYearString birthYearString
```

Also, in the last line, I swapped the arguments, as they appear to be in the wrong order in your example. Also I improved `yearDif` definition as per @Redu's comment.

Here are the answers on your questions.

1. You can check that applicative (and functor) operations are indeed applied, following the advice in the GHC's [User Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ApplicativeDo), namely, using the `-ddump-ds` compiler switch. I add a couple more switches below to make the output more succinct. I also show only excerpt concerning the `maybeAge` function.

   ```
   $ ghc appdo.hs -ddump-ds -dsuppress-type-applications -dsuppress-module-prefixes 
   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( appdo.hs, appdo.o )

   ==================== Desugar (after optimization) ====================
   Result size of Desugar (after optimization)
     = {terms: 75, types: 75, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
   ...
   -- RHS size: {terms: 17, types: 13, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
   maybeAge :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
   [LclId]
   maybeAge
     = \ (fS_a1h3 :: String) (bS_a1h4 :: String) ->
         <*>
           $fApplicativeMaybe
           (fmap
              $fFunctorMaybe
              (\ (fI_a1h5 :: Int) (bI_a1h6 :: Int) -> yearDiff fI_a1h5 bI_a1h6)
              (readMaybe $fReadInt fS_a1h3))
           (readMaybe $fReadInt bS_a1h4)
   ...
   ```
2. Most certainly, no speedup is gained here. Applicative opertaions for `Maybe` have constant complexity (`O(1)`) — just like the monadic ones.

   In the [original paper](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/applicativedo.pdf), the authors of `ApplicativeDo` give several examples of more sophisticated monadic types (`Haxl`, `Data.Seq`, parsing, etc.) allowing for asymptotically more efficient applicative operations. See Section 6 of the paper.