# Defining and using monadic structures on custom datatypes?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I'm getting to grips with functors, applicatives and monads.

These examples are just to illustrate the basics:

```
data User a = Age a deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

**Functor** (apply a non-context function to a single context datatype):

```
instance Functor User where
  fmap f (Age a) = Age (f a)

functorFunction :: Int -> Int
functorFunction e = e + 1

main = do
 print $ fmap functorFunction (Age 22)
```

**Applicative** (apply a simple function to multiple context datatypes):

```
instance Applicative User where
  pure a = Age a
  (<*>) (Age a) = fmap a

applicativeFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int
applicativeFunction e1 e2 = e1 + e2

main = do 
  print $ pure (applicativeFunction) <*> (Age 44) <*> (Age 65)
```

I've going through [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and haven't been able to find a simple explanation of

1) how to define a monad structure for my 'User a' type, and 2) what functionality a monad provides versus, say, an applicative functor?

Comment: Your `User` type is isomorphic to [the `Identity` functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity). Have a look at [its source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Identity.html#line-97)

Comment: Regarding 2, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38719766/3072788).

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409260/what-advantage-does-monad-give-us-over-an-applicative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) how to define a monad structure for my 'User a' type

(Preliminary note: Learn You a Haskell predates `Applicative` becoming a superclass of `Monad`. For that reason, and unlike the book suggests, with recent versions of GHC there is no need of implementing `return` -- by default, it is the same as `pure`. That being so, I will jump directly to `(>>=)`.)

One nice thing about methods with very general types such as `(>>=)`...

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

... is that they are so general that there are few sensible ways of implementing them -- often just one. If we specialise `(>>=)` for your type, we get:

```
(>>=) @User :: User a -> (a -> User b) -> User b
```

So `(>>=)` is supposed to take an `User a` and an `a -> User b` and use them to produce an `User b`. Given that the function takes an `a` value, the first thing to try is looking for an `a` value to pass to it. We do have such a value: the one wrapped by the `Age` constructor in the `User a` value:

```
instance Monad User where
    (Age a) >>= f = f a
```

To write a `Monad` instance in good conscience, we should check whether it follows the monad laws:

```
return a >>= f = f a

m >>= return = m

(m >>= f) >>= g = m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

That can be done with (your favourite equivalent of) pen and paper:

```
return a >>= f = f a
Age a >>= f = f a
f a = f a

m >>= return = m
Age a >>= return = Age a -- [*]
Age a >>= Age = Age a
Age a = Age a 

-- [*]: Both here and in the next law, we can replace 'm' by 'Age a'
--      because there is just one constructor. If there were more
--      (as in e.g. data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a), we would have
--      to check the law holds for all constructors.  

(m >>= f) >>= g = m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
(Age a >>= f) >>= g = Age a >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
f a >>= g = (\x -> f x >>= g) a
f a >>= g = f a >>= g
```

> 2) what functionality a monad provides versus, say, an applicative functor?

Here I will leave it to [the question arrowd suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17409260/2751851). I will only note that your example doesn't give you enough to really appreciate the difference, as the `User` context is too simple to let you do anything interesting with `(>>=)` (as Benjamin Hodgson points out, it is isomorphic to `Identity`, the dummy functor). `Maybe`, which is used by the accepted answer of the linked question, is quite a bit more illustrative.